# Spring data jpa @transactional

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Below is the flow of my application

Controller - services - repository

At the service layer we have `@Transactional` annotation
We also have `jpa:repository` configuration where we specify the entity manager and txn manager.

My doubt is I feel that the txn manager specified in `jpa:repositories` is considered and there is no impact of specifying `@Transactional` at service layer. 
For eg : the service layer `@Transactional` can be mapped to custom txn manager where as the repository invoked by the service may have a different txn manager. In that case won't it create a problem?

Can Somebody clarify do we ever need to put `@Transactional` at service layer when we are using jpa repository ?

Comment: Transactions must not be demarcated at the DAO layer: a single unit of work will usually use several DAOs, and be orchestrated by a single transactional service method. Why would you define 2 different transaction managers since you only want one?

Comment: Yes... Because when you do multiple database calls you want a single transaction NOT multiple. Hence you need a transaction started at the service level.

Comment: Agree. There is a design issue in the current implementation. The service invokes repostories connecting to two different schema ( these are pure select queries and not JTA ) .That is the reason the jpa repositories are configured with different entity manager factory and different txn manager.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

See section 2.3 of the Spring Data Reference:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/#transactions

CRUD methods on your repository are transactional by default. While these transactions can be configured as required, it is normally the case, as suggested in the comments above, that transactions be specified at the Service layer and in that case:

> The transaction configuration at the repositories will be neglected
>   then as the outer transaction configuration determines the actual one
>   used.

So, in answer to your question, transactions can (and should be) specified at the service level regardless of any Spring Data transaction management.

Comment: Thanks - that was a very useful info.  I will retest in debug mode and verify the above.

Comment: I observed that the transaction interceptor at the Repository does not use the transactionManager started by the service layer .At the repository proxy , a search is performed to identify a bean by name "transactionManager" and that is being used. Is there any settign to be done if we want the spring jpa data to be part of the transaction started by the service layer