# One transaction for several JpaRepositories' methods

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

I have some autowired interfaces extends JpaRepository. Each of them has "update" hql method, for different entities. I'm calling these methods from service's method.

How i can make all of them executing in ONE transaction for rolling back all data, if one of them will fail?

service has attribuites @service & @transactional, but it doesnt help.

------------------------ update

Here an example. repository1.updateMethod() and repository2.updateMethod() works fine, repository3.save throws exception bacause of constraint error. In result, i see that results of repository1 and repository2 methods saved. I need it to roll back.

```
@ Service
@ Transactional(rollbackFor = {RuntimeException.class})
public SomeService {
  @ Autowired SomeRepository repository1;
  @ Autowired AnotherRepository repository2;
  @ Autowired ThirdRepository repository3;
  ...
  @ Transactional(rollbackFor = {RuntimeException.class})
  public void SomeMethod(SomeEntity obj, String someNewValue) {
    try {
      repository1.updateMethod();
      repository2.updateMethod();
      obj.setValue(someNewValue);
      repository3.save(obj);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: Exapndong on 'it doesn't work' and posting some code might help. See my previous comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716673/spring-data-jpa-transactional/19723602#19723602

Comment: Specifying `@transactional` at the service method level should make anything underneath that transactional, unless you have the transaction type set to "Requires New" or "Not Supported" on the sub-transactions, which will run those in their own transaction.  Are you testing this by throwing something in your CRUD, then checking if the transactions roll back all the way?  Can you share some code?

Comment: @CodeChimp First message was updated, i added example and expanded what I meant.

Comment: How do you get a reference to the service? Show us the code which uses the service.

Comment: One of-topic observation: You should include your exception when you throw your `RuntimeException`.  You are effectively gobbling up the cause, and will only get a blank `RuntimeException`.  Also, is there a reason why you limit the transactions to `RuntimeException` anyway?  Seems like you want all exceptions...not sure wrapping it in `RuntimeExcetion` buys you anything.

Comment: Also, when are you checking the DB?  After the method completely finished, or like while you have the debugger stopped somewhere in the method?

Comment: @CodeChimp of course after method completely finished. This code is an simplified example, but it shows the main idea of what i am doing.

Comment: @JBNizet "@ Autowired SomeService someService" and then "someService.someMethod(obj, value);". Bean declared at spring-servlet.xml

Comment: How are you setting up the Transaction Manager?

Comment: @CodeChimp just declared it in xml file (see below). I found one solution, I posted it in answer. But even with it i have some questions.

Comment: @Nikolay I am having the same issue...were you able to figure out why it didn't work with your configurations?

Answer (score 1):

I think i found one solution, but I still dont understand why it doesnt work with default usage.

First, I declared JpaTransactionManager at applidationData.xml

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

And used it in servise:

```
@Autowired
JpaTransactionManager jtm;
```

Before my code i added:

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
def.setName("TxName");
def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);
TransactionStatus ts = jtm.getTransaction(def);
```

And at the finish

```
jtm.commit(ts);
```

Now, if some method produces exception, it throws at the last line and all updates is rolling back. That is what i needed. But, as i said, I still dont understand why it doesnt work with default usage.

Comment: It's possible you have something setup wrong.  I think the `@Transactional` uses AOP under the covers, so maybe you are missing something key there?  Also, if you are going to rollback on an exception, you need to wrap your ts.rollback() in a try/catch of it's own.  Otherwise, and exception there will gobble up the one that cause the rollback in the first place.  You end up being blind to the true cause of the original exception.