# Transaction rollback not working for multiple repositories for spring JPA

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, spring-boot

Both of my transaction does not rollback, maybe I am missing on some core concepts.

```
@Autowired
CustomRepositoryA customrepositoryA

@Autowired
CustomRepositoryB customrepositoryB

@Transactional
public void method(){

//businesslogic

//works fine
customrepositoryA.save(obj);
customrepositoryA.flush();

//Error
customrepositoryB.save(obj);
customrepositoryB.flush();

}
```

So my understanding is that the @Transactional annotation should rollback both the repository transactions if there is an error but it just rollbacks for the second one the first transaction is persisted into DB.
Also does JPA repository provide a way to clear out session caches after flush equivalent to session.clear() in hibernate?

Here is the link to the same problem I am facing asked a few years ago
[One transaction for several JpaRepositories' methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953959/one-transaction-for-several-jparepositories-methods)

Comment: What kind of exception is thrown? Auto rollback is only for run time exceptions.

Comment: Yes its a runtime exception which I tried purposely to test rollback

Comment: Show the code calling that method.  Transaction is obviously not working.  First commit is done by the Spring data transaction as, despite the annotation,  there is no outer transaction running.