# Spring Data JPA - save() method working perfectly fine without using the returned entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Below is the Javadoc specific for the save() method in Spring Data JPA

```
/**
 * Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the
 * entity instance completely.
 * 
 * @param entity
 * @return the saved entity
 */
<S extends T> S save(S entity);
```

and also below resource clearly states that we need to use the returned objected to ensure that we perform further operations on the saved entity.

[Why to use returned instance after save() on Spring Data JPA Repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625150/why-to-use-returned-instance-after-save-on-spring-data-jpa-repository)

However, in my below code my save() entity works fine without

```
public void createEmployee(Employee employee) throws Exception {
    try {
        employee.setEmployeeName("alan");   
        employeeRepo.save(employee);
        employee.setEmployeeType("Permanent");  
        employeeRepo.save(employee); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    }

}
```

1. Why is the above code working without a return type
2. Tests seem to show that data is being persisted perfectly fine, but i was under the impression that we need to use the returned entity to ensure correct persistence.

Am I doing something inadvertently right/wrong ? I am new to spring-data and would like to understand save() method perfectly since a lot of my current application is CRUD based. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The save() method of SimpleJpaRepository is as below:

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#save(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

For a new entity instance it does not actually matter as the `save()` method returns the same instance.

Note that (assuming you have an active transaction at the service layer) your code should work even without the 2nd call to `save()` as the initial call to `save()` will delegate to `EntityManager.persist()` which will make the employee instance managed and tracked: any changes made to the entity within an active transaction will be automatically flushed to the database on transaction commit (See further : http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/managed).

```
public void createEmployee(Employee employee) throws Exception {
    try {
        employee.setEmployeeName("alan");   
        employeeRepo.save(employee);
        employee.setEmployeeType("Permanent");  
        //employeeRepo.save(employee); <- not required : type should still be 'Permanent' in DB.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. "For a new entity instance it does not actually matter as the save() method returns the same instance" -> Can you please clarify....in what situations is a difference instance created ? 2. What do you mean by "active transaction" ....I am using Spring Data and since the transactions are being managed by Spring Data, i am probably confused. Everyone speaks of active transaction, what exactly is it in Spring Data context ? Thanks

Comment: You really need to understand the underlying JPA API as Spring Data is of course only an abstraction over this `EntityManager.merge(..)` vs `EntityManager.persist(..)`. **Point 1**: when you are updating an existing instance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1070629/1356423 **Point 2**. Transactions are typically defined at the service layer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19723602/1356423

Comment: Many thanks for the excellent resources. Also, Why is my above code working without a Return type in Save ?