# Spring data updates entity without transaction

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have simple code example with Spring Data:

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;
//...
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
}
```

Service with example methods:

```
@Service
public class CarService {

    @Autowired
    private CarRepository carRepository;

    public void change() {
        Car one = carRepository.findOne(1L);
        one.setName("changed"); //important
    }
}
```

And controller:

```
@RestController("/")
public class CarController {

    @Autowired
    private CarRepository carRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CarService carService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Car> home() {
        carService.change();
        List<Car> all = carRepository.findAll();

        return all;
    }

}
```

I also have data.sql with 3 records:

```
insert into car values (1, 'aaa');
insert into car values (2, 'bbb');
insert into car values (3, 'ccc');
```

When I send request to the localhost:8080 I get list with three cars, where the first one is updated:

```
insert into car values (1, 'changed');
insert into car values (2, 'bbb');
insert into car values (3, 'ccc');
```

My expectation is that after calling change() from controller actually nothing happens because this method is not transactional. So why my home() method in controller returns list with updated entity?

This question is completly different from this [Spring data jpa @transactional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716673/spring-data-jpa-transactional) I don't understand why you mark this as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring data jpa @transactional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716673/spring-data-jpa-transactional)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume, that you are using Spring Boot. If you use Spring Boot with Spring MVC and Spring Data, by default a Hibernate Session will be opened every time your controller methods receive a request. A Session provides a physical connectivity between your application and database. This functionality can be controlled with the `spring.jpa.open-in-view` application property.

```
Car one = carRepository.findOne(1L); //1
one.setName("changed"); //2
List<Car> all = carRepository.findAll(); //3
return all;
```

1. A session will be open, when the program reaches the code above.
   On the first line, the Car object is retrieved from the DB, and the object is stored in the `First Level Cache`.
2. As the "*one*" reference points to the same object, that is in the cache, at line 2 the cached objects name changes.
3. On the third line we get the cached value for the object, that we retrieved earlier, and that value is returned at the end.

Since the modified value is never flushed to the DB, after your controller call you can check your DB, and you will see, that the old value remained for your object, despite you received a different value in the controller response.

If you set the `spring.jpa.open-in-view` property to *false*, your controllers will return the "correct" value.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Spring Data documentation methods are transactional!

> 4.7. Transactionality
>
> CRUD methods on repository instances are transactional by default. For reading operations the transaction
> configuration readOnly flag is set to true, all others are configured
> with a plain @Transactional so that default transaction configuration
> applies. For details see JavaDoc of SimpleJpaRepository.

Read the full documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions

Comment: You don't understand the question. The problem is not in spring data repository, but in change() method that is simple service and IS NOT transactional

Answer (score 0):

A) The default behavior of a Spring Data JPARepository is to return a Attached Entity.  If you perform an update on that attached object within the same persistent session then the changes to the persistent state are updated when the session is flushed.

B) The methods on a Spring Data Repository by default are transactional.  The default settings are:

```
 propagation  REQUIRED
 isolation    DEFAULT
 timeout      -1
 read-only    false
```

C) Lastly your home() method marks the beginning and end of the transaction and JPA session.  Once the session is used the TransactionManager creates the session.  Once the method completes the transaction is committed or rolled back and the JPA session is flushed and closed.

I hope that helps explain your result.

Comment: A) Yes, but change() method IS NOT transactional, so the session is not flushed. B) I know that, but in this case I don;t see connection with provided example. C) I don't understand why home() starts transaction if there is no @Transactional annotation?

Comment: Have you configured your transaction manager to be annotation-driven?
<tx:annotation-driven /> .  Can you please include details of your spring configuration file?  Do you have tx:advice and aop:config configuration specified?  This will drive to which classes default transaction management semantics are applied.  Those details will be helpful to explain.

Comment: this is hello world example, there is only default spring boot configuration and only datasource configuration in application.xml

Answer (score 0):

if you are using hibernate as your ORM tool , this might occur due to dirty checking .If you modify an object that is known by the hibernate session, it will automatically be saved by hibernate when session is flushed